# Installing PHP 5.3 Pear on centos 5.8

Tags: centos5, memcached, php53

I just created a VPS with 32 bit Centos 5.8 and installed php53 and a host of other php 5.3 packages. I would like to install memcached using yum but I get the following error

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcached.i386 0:1.0.0-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-zend-abi = 20050922 for package: php-pecl-memcached
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2) for package: php-pecl-memcached
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2 for package: php-pecl-memcached
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmemcached.i386 0:0.31-1.1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package php-common.i386 0:5.1.6-40.el5_9 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: php53-common conflicts php-common
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-common-5.3.3-13.el5_9.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
--> php53-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                    package-cleanup --dupes
                    rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Tried package cleanup and everything else mentioned in the message above but still wasn't able to install so I wanted to install it from the PECL libraries and proceeded to install PEAR for PHP5.3

```
yum install php53-pear
```

I get an error

```
No package php53-pear available.
Nothing to do
```

So I tried (dumb thing to do!)

```
yum install php-pear
```

and managed to install. Followed it by

```
pecl install memcached
```

and I get the following errors
    building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/memcached-2.1.0
    running: /tmp/tmpCW9TMv/memcached-2.1.0/configure
    checking for egrep... grep -E
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
    checking for cc... no
    checking for gcc... no
    configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
    See `config.log' for more details.
    ERROR:`/tmp/tmpCW9TMv/memcached-2.1.0/configure' failed

I am kind of struck. Is there a way to install PEAR for PHP5.3 on Centos 5.8 and install memcached as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have 2 version of php: 5.1.6 and 5.3.3

```
Processing Conflict: php53-common conflicts php-common
```

I will suggest to add ius community repo and install all necessary packages from them. Install from source it's a bad idea on RHEL based system, imho

```
# rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm    
# rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/i386/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
# yum install php53u-pear php53u-pecl-memcached
```

Comment: Never tried this. But will on my next VPS. I would probably be better of installing Centos 6

Comment: Couldn't resist trying this. So installed everying from the ius repos.
ius community repositories is the best bet for someone looking to retain php 5.3 and still have pecl. Thank you ALex_hha

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a compiler (and probably also php headers). Try

```
yum install gcc php53-devel
```

first. Then

```
pecl install memcached
```

again.

Comment: I had installed php52-devl right in the beginning. I installed gcc and tried installing memcached. NO LUCK :-(

Comment: What error message do you get after installing gcc?

Comment: bash: pecl: command not found

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is the conflict between the PHP 5.3.3 common files and the PHP 5.1.6 files, yum is telling you this here:

```
php53-common-5.3.3-13.el5_9.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
--> php53-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
```

To resolve, simply remove php-common then run your original yum command again.

```
yum remove php-common
yum install php-pecl-memcached
```

Unless you've got a specific requirement, I'd suggest sticking to the packaged versions of these files rather than compiling from source.

edit: You may want to clear out all of the php packages and start again:

```
rpm -qa | grep php | xargs rpm -e
```

Comment: I cleared out all the packages.
    $yum remove php-common
    Package(s) php-common available, but not installed.
    No Packages marked for removal
Then
   $yum install php-pecl-memcached
Funny it reinstalled php-common of php 5.1 but did not throw conflicts. Nevertheless memcached is installed.
Thank you James Yale.